# webapge is not loading in android app

Tags: android, android-webview

I tried [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm'). It's working fine. I want to implement a app that loads Google page directly.

I edited code. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    }

    public void open(View view) {
        String myurl = "https://www.google.com";
        browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browser.loadUrl(myurl);
       }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
          }
       }    
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sinlge.MainActivity" >

<WebView
      android:id="@+id/webView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not giving any error but showing white page.

Comment: your code is perfect but just call open() function in oncreat or anywhere you want. withoud calling open function url not load..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
String myurl = "https://www.google.com";
browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
browser.loadUrl(myurl);
```

in `onCreate` after

```
browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

Because I am not able to see from where `public void open(View view)` is being called.

Comment: Thanks. My bad, in xml they are calling at onClick. I didn't saw that.

Comment: Ho @MD, I'm unable to communicate with google page. How I can search something in that page?